# Limit number of selected checkbox, but allow to unselect a checkbox Angular 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, checkbox

I checked other threads, but no one with Typescript and not Jquery.

I would like to be able to select 2 checkbox, but no more. I would to keep the ability to unselect a previous one that has been selected.
I'm using Typescript with Angular 10. No Jquery, and i don't want it.

Actually : I can select 2 checkbox, and then they are ALL disabled. So i can't unselect a previous one..

Html :

```
<nb-checkbox [disabled]="disableCheckbox()" (change)="changeSelection($event, item.id)" [checked]="false">A checkbox</nb-checkbox>
```

Typescript :

```
checkboxList = [];
public maxElementCheckbox = 2;

changeSelection($event, id){

    if ($event.target.checked) {
      this.checkboxList.push(id);
    }  else {
      this.checkboxList.splice(this.checkboxList.indexOf(id), 1);
    }
    console.log(this.checkboxList);
  }

  public disableCheckbox(): boolean {
    return this.checkboxList.length >= this.maxElementCheckbox;
  }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current setup, you can just add a check to your disableCheckbox function to see if the id for that checkbox exists in your checkboxList array. This will prevent the checkbox getting disabled if it is selected.

```
<nb-checkbox [disabled]="disableCheckbox(item.id)" (change)="changeSelection($event, item.id)" [checked]="false">A checkbox</nb-checkbox>
```

```
  public disableCheckbox(id): boolean {
    return this.checkboxList.length >= this.maxElementCheckbox && !this.checkboxList.includes(id);
  }
```

Comment: It's just perfect. Easy and clean :)